# Opening a vba-created calendar from another userform?

Tags: excel, vba, date, calendar, userform

In 64-bit MS Office there is no more Date-Picker.

I have found a VBA-created calendar, consisting of of a class and a userform.

- [Original Page](http://blog.clearbyte.ch/vba-kalender-steuerelement-fuer-office-2010/)
- [English Translation of Page](https://translate.google.ca/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.clearbyte.ch%2Fvba-kalender-steuerelement-fuer-office-2010%2F&edit-text=&act=url)

I have imported the elements into my Excel file.

How could I open the calendar from my Userform2? My Userform2 has a field for date value. A call the Userform with a button then how could I call the calendar from my Userform2?

I am quite a beginner in VBA, I would prefer a detailed answer :)

Comment: Within Userform2 you could add a Button (or something else) and then open the Calender with `frmCalendar.Show`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Regional issue with the control

Although handy, this control will generate errors for those trying to use it outside of Germany (and possibly even within Germany) since it's hard-coded to rely on a date format of "`dd.mm.yyyy`" — which hasn't been an [official date standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country#Listing) standard *anywhere (including Germany)* since 1996.

To fix the issue, replace each of the four offending lines with the below alternatives, which instead use the [**`DateSerial`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/dateserial-function) function as an "international date handling solution".  (The quickest way to locate them in `frmCalendar` is to search the project for "`01.`".)

```
intDayCounter = Weekday(DateSerial(dYear, dMonth, 1), vbMonday)  


datLastDayMonth = fLastDayInMonth(DateSerial(dYear, dMonth, 1))  


Me.Controls(strLabel).Caption = Mid(fLastDayInMonth(_
    DateSerial(dYear, dMonth - 1, 1)), 1, 2) - intVormonat  


Me.Controls(strLabel).Caption = Mid(fLastDayInMonth(_
    DateSerial(dYear - 1, dMonth + 11, 1)), 1, 2) - intVormonat
```

---

### Using the control is a userform

To add this custom control with on your userform:

- Add a command button to your user form
- Right-click the new button and click **`View Code`**
- Paste the code below into the ***`_Click()`*** procedure for your button

---

```
frmCalendar.Show  
TextBox1 = g_datCalendarDate
```

...where `TextBox1` is the name of the control where you want the selected date.

Clicking the button will now open the calendar, allow the user to select a date, close the calendar, and populate the specified control with the selected date.

[image]

Comment: ashleedawg, you are amazing. With this command button Task I could avoid the Problem, that I could not close the calendar in 64 bit Office. :)

Comment: Many people (myself included) have had problems with the ActiveX `Microsoft Date & Time Picker` (and the previous version wasn't much better).  I like the one you found, it's simple and does the job it's supposed to.  I've added it to my personal library. :-)  (My mother would say, *"Na sicher, es ist Deutsch, also ist es das Beste!"* since anything else is apparently crap,  lol)

Answer (score -1):

If the calendar is contained within a userform, find the name of that userform, then add a command button to Userform2 and use code similar to:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
        dateUserfom.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: @ Christian T  - Welcome to [so]!  Unfortunately, your example would not have displayed the selected date on the OP's subform.  (Also, it's a good idea to test an answer prior to posting...see: [answer])

Comment: To be fair, the question asks how to open the calendar not populate the subform.

Comment: I am a very beginner in VBA. After I could put value in TextBox, another Problem came (I could not close the calendar). This command button in Userform could help to avoid this bug in Excel.